# Drop partial duplicates in Pandas based on which has least information

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas, and wondering if I can use it for something specific. I want to drop rows of a dataframe which have a partial duplicate entry in a certain column.

For example, if there are two rows, and one row has "Verrucomicrobia;phylum;" in a given column, and the second row has "Verrucomicrobia;phylum;Opitutae;class;" in that column, I want to drop the first row.

I want to from this:

```
                                        0   1
0                 Verrucomicrobia;phylum;  10
1  Verrucomicrobia;phylum;Opitutae;class;   5
```

to this:

```
                                        0  1
0  Verrucomicrobia;phylum;Opitutae;class;  5
```

But there is no unique string that I am looking for- I am just looking to get rid of the row with partial duplicate but less information. The above is one example.

Also, there might be three rows, and I want to get rid of the two with least information.

In that case, I want to go from this:

```
                                                   0   1
0                            Verrucomicrobia;phylum;  10
1             Verrucomicrobia;phylum;Opitutae;class;   5
2  Verrucomicrobia;phylum;Opitutae;class;Puniceic...   3
```

to this:

```
                                                   0  1
0  Verrucomicrobia;phylum;Opitutae;class;Puniceic...  3
```

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Yes, please post some sample data illustrating  your request along with expected output.

Comment: Added expected output, thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind pointing me in the right direction, I would appreciate it, even if you don't want to answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Generate some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [';'.join([str(randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(randint(1, 5))]) for __ in range(100000)]
})

print(df)

                   0
0              71;39
1           72;75;92
2              45;74
3         55;94;95;3
4      27;93;4;33;52
...              ...
9995              64
9996  36;71;36;69;74
9997           53;30
9998            8;35
9999  47;63;68;99;18

[10000 rows x 1 columns]
```

## With progress bar

```
import itertools as it
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm  # for jupyter notebook, else just "from tqdm import tqdm" 

# Turn your semi-colon seperated strings into lists
df[0] = df[0].str.split(';')

# You have trailing semi-colons, so we remove empty strings from the column
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda lst: [item for item in lst if not item == ''])

# We make a list of values (lists) we want to drop
to_drop = []

# Get the total number of comparisons, for the progress bar
n = (len(df) * (len(df)-1)) // 2 

# Comparing all lists with all other lists, we append them to to_drop if 
# they contain any of the same elements
for a, b in tqdm(it.combinations(df[0], 2), total=n):
    if not set(a).isdisjoint(b):
        to_drop.append(b)

# Drop duplicates, like list(set(lst)) but for list of lists
to_drop = list(k for k,_ in it.groupby(to_drop))

# Filter
res = df[df[0].apply(lambda lst: lst not in to_drop)]
print(res)
```

## Without progress bar:

```
import itertools as it

# Turn your semi-colon seperated strings into lists
df[0] = df[0].str.split(';')

# You have trailing semi-colons, so we remove empty strings from the column
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda lst: [item for item in lst if not item == ''])

# We make a list of values (lists) we want to drop
to_drop = []

# Comparing all lists with all other lists, we append them to to_drop if 
# they contain any of the same elements
for a, b in it.combinations(df[0], 2):
    if not set(a).isdisjoint(b):
        to_drop.append(b)

# Drop duplicates, like list(set(lst)) but for list of lists
to_drop = list(k for k,_ in it.groupby(to_drop))

# Filter
res = df[df[0].apply(lambda lst: lst not in to_drop)]
```

**Output**

```
                       0
0               [71, 39]
1           [72, 75, 92]
2               [45, 74]
3        [55, 94, 95, 3]
4    [27, 93, 4, 33, 52]
5   [49, 91, 28, 28, 20]
6               [31, 69]
8       [51, 59, 41, 17]
10          [79, 19, 62]
21      [89, 48, 56, 34]
52             [100, 50]
85              [77, 97]
```

Comment: Note, if you have a very large amount of data, this make take some time as it compares all pairs of cell values in the for loop, which is n(n-1)/2 comparisons, where n is the length of your dataframe.

Comment: This is working great, except it's dropping the rows with the most information rather than the least. I will try to figure out how to reverse it, but let me know if you know of a simple fix. Thank you again.

Comment: Looks like changing to_drop.append(b) to to_drop.append(a) fixed it.

Comment: Argh, sorry one more problem. I don't want to drop rows if they contain ANY of the same elements, just if ALL of their elements are contained in other rows. This code is dropping too much.

Comment: I got it! I'm using issubset() instead of isdisjoint()